# Group buying via paypal?

Tags: php, html, paypal, e-commerce

I have never worked with paypal thus I do not know any of the functionality that I could use to benefit me. The user experience that I want to achieve is this: 150 items must be bought before your account is charged, otherwise no money goes from your account. I was thinking I could use paypal's [bill me later](https://personal.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=marketing_us/BillMeLater_ProductOverview). However that seems more customer oriented.

Do you know if paypal is feasible for this task, and if so which service?

Comment: you're talking about an account. My guess is that there's already some data associated w/ user. Wondering why don't you do something like having some sort of counter also. You let everything go until the 150 limit is reached; and then you go for a unique paypal payment. Not sure whether this can address your problem... just my 2cc

Comment: @maraspin so you mean people would just say they want to buy it. Then when they reach 150 they all proceed to a unique checkout. Isn't that trusting that they will actually buy it a little too much.

Comment: That's what I was asking myself too ;-) But what I've understood from your question nevertheless. Isn't it your goal to wait until they purchase 150 items and then charge'em?

Comment: Oops poor wording. 150 users must buy this item before any one is charged. Not one user buying 150

Comment: Is there a time limit to reach 150 items? You may want to check out how [Authorization & Capture](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide/HowAuthCaptureWorks.html) work. With this, you may request authorization for payment up to a certain amount for an item, and can capture the payment at a later date (up to 29 days, I believe).

Comment: Two words: preapproved payments. I don't have the links at hand at the moment (hence no full answer), but with Adaptive Preapproved payments you'll be able to accomplish what you want. There are some StackOverflow answer on the topic as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to depart from PayPal, there are other Payment authorizers that will store a customers' info and let you bill them later.

You might take a look at Stripe. 
https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges

```
# create a Customer
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :card => token,
  :description => "payinguser@example.com".  
)

# At a later time, charge the Customer
Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => 1000, # in cents.
    :currency => "usd",
    :customer => customer.id. 
)
```